# How to validate usability of software frameworks

Tags: research, software-testing, empirical-research, api-design

My thesis will produce a software framework that can be used by programmers to solve problems in a paticular domain.
One of the case studies I want to do to verify the contribution I'm making is to have some measure of usability of the framework.
I'm looking for techniques to test a software framework that will be used by other programmers, not so much end users.
When including 'usability' in my searches the results lead to end-user UX/UI usability.

I ultimately want to run a test where one or a few programmer try to use the framework on a given problem. To help make sure the test has usable results I want to plan the strategy before hand and first consider existing techniques. But finding existing research or tests about usability of code libraries/frameworks is difficult to find.

Please let me know if you can think of a way to validate the usability of my software framework.

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: Is there a specific reason "generic" usability metrics (i.e., effectiveness, efficiency, and satisfaction) would not apply in your setting?

Comment: While not off-topic here, this question may receive better answers on either [ux.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. However, please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) (so delete it here if you decide to post it elsewhere). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @dkaeae I'm looking for applications of those generic metrics applied to a software framework to help me back up the claim that doing such tests would actually be reliable, usable and trustworthy. I don't want to run into problems later down the line once the test(s) have been done

Comment: @Discretelizard Any way I can cross-post this question there directly without making a new question there?

Comment: @marita3952 No. I mean, I _can_ migrate this question if you really want to (which is mainly useful to move answers together with the question), but if there are no answers yet, it is a lot easier if you just copy the question and delete it here.